# How to handle event on Search button on keyboard which comes when we use PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, placeautocompletefragment

PlaceAutocompleteFragment implementation is working fine, as it should work. On Click on PlaceAutocompleteFragment, I am able to search places.

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            Toast.makeText(AroundMe.this, "" + place.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Toast.makeText(AroundMe.this, "" + status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Post-click on search result item list, I'm able to get Places details inside onPlaceSelected() method.

**Here is what I am looking for:**

1. On click of PlaceAutocompleteFragment, KeyBoard comes & there is search button on bottom right. **I want to handle the event on that search button**. But currently on click on search button, keyboard hides.

I have already tried this way, but it's not working.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) autocompleteFragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    Toast.makeText(AroundMe.this, "check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Also tried this way, but still it's not working.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) autocompleteFragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input);
    editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.getAction()== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH){
                switch (keyCode){
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH:
                        Toast.makeText(AroundMe.this, "check" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am not sure,but may be its not possible. I tried to dive in the fragment code of placeautofragment. they keyboard is sort of independent of the edit text.